# initialize my framework's variables from project

Tags: swift, frameworks

I am currently using public static variables in my framework which I can change from a project using the framework.

```
//In framework
public class MyConstants {
    public static var someText = "text1"
}


//In project
import MyFramework
MyConstants.sometext = "text2"
```

And this works fine. But I would like to implement a nicer way to change a set of variables. e.g. with an init function.
I looked into using a Singleton, but it has a private initializer, so that's not an option. Any idea how to implement this using a public initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Still open for ideas, I just haven't seen much written about best practices when it comes to frameworks.

But I came up with this:

```
//In framework
public class MyConstants {

    static var v1 = ""
    static var v2 = ""

    public static func setVariables(v1: String, v2: String) {
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
    }
}


//In project
MyConstants.setVariables(v1: "a", v2: "b")
```